# Selecting filtered rows in excel using VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-interop, office-automation, excel-automation

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Program
    Dim oxl As Excel.Application
    Dim owbs As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim owb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim osheets As Excel.Worksheets
    Dim osheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim owr, newRng, rngVisible As Excel.Range
    Sub Main()
        oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oxl.Visible = True
        owb = CType(oxl.Workbooks.Open("G:\TestData\Matthews Fund"), Excel.Workbook)
        osheet = CType(owb.Worksheets("Holdings"), Excel.Worksheet)
        owr = CType(osheet.Range("A13:G68"), Excel.Range)

        'Resizing selected range to exclude header row
        newRng = owr.Offset(1).Resize(owr.Rows.Count - 1)

        'Applying autofilter on the resized range and setting criterion to field 3
        newRng.AutoFilter(Field:=3, Criteria1:="=India")

        'Trying to select the filtered rows
        'but this step is not working properly as non adjacent rows are not getting selected
        rngVisible = newRng.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)

        'Row 14 and Row 26 are 2 rows which are getting filtered out based on the condition
        'However no of rows is displayed as 1 and not 2 - only row 14 is being selected
        'Probable reason: Row 14 and Row 26 are not adjacent
        Console.WriteLine("No of filtered rows: {0}", rngVisible.Rows.count)

        'Any easy/direct way to select the non-adjacent filtered rows in a single range obj?
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

As explained in the comments in the code, the result of applying the auto filter to `newRng` is that two rows, Row 14 and Row 26 are getting filtered out. But when I try to select those two rows, I am unable to. So, is there any easy/direct way to select the non-adjacent filtered rows in a single range obj?

A final point: I found some [useful info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557713/applying-auto-filter-on-excel-sheet-through-vb-net) here. But the solution here seems to be deleting the filtered rows. i do not want to delete the filtered rows.

Comment: A non-contiguous range has an [`Areas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.areas?view=excel-pia) collection. `rngVisible.Rows.count` reports on the first Area in that collection.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks...perfectly selecting the filtered ranges